# How to change legend in shape of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a trouble about the legend of shape in R.

I used ggplot to draw a graph like this:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=ex1score,y=ex2score,shape=m_shape,color=m_shape))+  
  geom_point()
```

[image]

But I want to change:

> m_shape --> result
>
> 0--> fail
>
> 1-->pass

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=ex1score,y=ex2score,shape=m_shape,color=m_shape))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_discrete(labels=c("fail","pass"),name="result")+
  scale_shape_discrete(labels=c("fail","pass"),name="result")
```

I don't think you can get away with only specifying the labels and name once since `m_shape` affects both shape and color

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
Actually, m_shape is the label. I want to present they in two different shapes with different colour. Could you have any better solution for my case. Thanks

Comment: You could show your data or a sample of your data (using `dput()` for example) to make sure I understand what you mean by "m_shape is the label"?